# How can I protect a source file when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I've got an app that uses our DAL and when I run it in debug mode (vs2010) and purposely try to make the app crash (for instance, leave the connection string empty of the DAL), vs2010 opens the code for the DAL at the point in which it crashed.  Which is ok, but I'm then able to edit that .cs file and save changes, which I don't want.  I've verified this by having the DAL project opened in another instance of vs2010 and when I make the app crash and change the DAL.cs in the app and save it, the DAL in vs2010 tells me that the file has been modified outside the project and asks if I want to reload it.

How can I prevent this from happening?  The only reference I am using to DAL in my app is the reference to the DLL, that's all.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent that? Source-level debugging is extremely useful.

Comment: Confucius say: If you do not want something that which you have just done, why did you do it?

Comment: Not looking to prevent Source-level debugging.  I just don't want another employee (someone less experienced) to change the DAL and potentially mess up the DAL.  More specifically, if they alter something that would effect other apps.

Comment: @Robert: Then deny them checkout access in source control.

Answer (score 1):

The `AssemblyName.pdb` file links the compiled DLL to the original source.
Visual Studio uses this file to display the source code when debugging.

You can delete this file and get rid of the source link.
This will give you a vastly inferior debugging experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to "Tools > Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue" and unchecking "Enable Edit and Continue"?

Answer (score 0):

**Make the `.cs` file(s) read-only.** If its read-only, you'll be able to *see* it, but you won't be able to save changes. (Depending on your Visual Studio settings, you might still be able to *edit* the file in memory, but that seems irrelevant, since the changes you make won't be persisted to disk.)

If you need more fine-grained control (like where *you* want to be able to edit the source files, but not your testers), you can use [access control lists (ACLs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc982153.aspx). Ask more questions about that on Server Fault.

Yes, you could disable debugging or turn off the generation of PDB files, but that makes it very difficult to debug the code, which is probably the reason why you're purposely trying to make the app crash.